# How can I get promises to work in IE?

Tags: javascript, promise, requirejs, html2canvas

In my html, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/html2canvas/html2canvas-master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

To solve other issues I had to upgrade to the version of html2canvas that uses Promises, but found that this is supported in IE (11).

I downloaded the library "es6-promise-master" as suggested by the maker of html2canvas. This is located in `js/libs/es6-promise-master`.

In my main javascript file, I have:

```
var Promise = require(['es6-promise']).Promise;
```

I cannot get this to work. My latest error in javascript is:

```
require.js: Line: 7
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(c){return b(a,c)}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

I have read http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch but I really need some code to figure out how to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax:

```
var Promise = require(['es6-promise']).Promise;
```

assumes you have a CommonJS environment available. This is provided by tools like Webpack and Browserify.

You're using RequireJS at the moment - this is something different than CommonJS and uses a different format for modules.

The easiest way to use that Promise implementation would be to include a polyfill that will automatically install itself when you include the script in your page. This is provided as [`es6-promise.auto.js`](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise#downloads).

Comment: How do I include that and what do I need to change in my code?

Comment: Nevermind, all I had to do was include `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>` in my html file. I honestly didn't even know CommonJS was a specific thing, I just thought they were referring to regular old JS.

Comment: Regular old JS doesn't have a concept of modules. Now there are CommonJS modules as seen in node.js, AMD modules used by require, and ES6 modules as defined in the latest Javascript standard